# Installed eclipse RCP plugin doesnt run

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-jdt

I was trying to install a sample plugin as mentioned here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html#jdt_example
into the eclipse instance but when i restart my eclipse i dont see the output on the console when i click on a new menu entry (new plugin). When i do ss pluginname i get active status and diag also shows no constraints . i am able to see the output only when i run it as an eclipse app.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the Console View that only shows the output of programs run from Eclipse. It does not show the output of 'System.out.println' statements in a plugin.

If you start Eclipse with the -consoleLog option it should show you a separate window with the console output from Eclipse.